# Getting only sale_order not having NULL order_line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having this table Sale_Order:

```
OrderId TotalAmount
1       200
2       560
52      4220
```

and I have the table Order_Line :

```
OrderLineId OrderId ProductId
12          1       5
5           2       56
```

I want to return only Sale_Order having matching Order_Line like below :

```
 OrderId TotalAmount
 1       200
 2       560
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple inner join would be BEST option in case as joins would run faster than sub query. Please check [Link](https://www.essentialsql.com/subquery-versus-inner-join/) for details

```
SELECT 
   sd.OrderId,
   sd.TotalAmount
FROM 
   Sales_Order sd
INNER JOIN 
   Order_Line ol
 ON
   (sd.OrderId = ol.OrderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try EXISTS :

```
select * from sale_order as so where exists (select * from sale_order_line as sol where so.orderid=sol.order_id)
```